# Is there a way to compare multiple results against each other from a dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm trying to backtest a model where I have many different instances of a result.

Basically, I want to see how well my metric (BlendGroup) does at predicting the Results (FieldAdjStrokes) in head to head situations.

I want to know if there's a way to set up all of the permutations for a particular Round & End_Date to see how well the metric tests out.

I'm not sure if that makes a ton of sense, I'm relatively new so take it easy on me, please! Thanks in advance!

```
   Year Event_Name             Name            pid   Round end_date            FieldAdjStrokes BlendGroups  
  <int> <chr>                  <chr>           <chr> <int> <dttm>                        <dbl> <fct>        
1  2018 Travelers Championship Smylie Kaufman  46440     1 2018-06-24 00:00:00          10.2   2.5 and Worse
2  2019 Valero Texas Open      Smylie Kaufman  46440     1 2019-04-07 00:00:00          -0.352 2.5 and Worse
3  2018 AT&T Byron Nelson      Smylie Kaufman  46440     1 2018-05-20 00:00:00           7.44  2.5 and Worse
4  2018 Barbasol Championship  Carl Pettersson 25345     1 2018-07-22 00:00:00           6.74  2.5 and Worse
5  2019 AT&T Byron Nelson      Smylie Kaufman  46440     1 2019-05-12 00:00:00           6.25  2.5 and Worse
```

Comment: When you say *"predicting"*, what exactly are you trying to do? If you want to know mathematically what regression/prediction can be done based on the type of data you have, then this question is more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and should be migrated. If you have something in mind, please make this question *reproducible* by adding relevant code (but not *too much*, enough that we can run something given what you give us).

Comment: I’m trying to backrest the results. I want to see if the metric I came up with actually predicts the results that I already have. I want to check all the combinations within the Round & End-Date.

Comment: Okay. When you say *"all of the permutations"*, can you show how you might run two different permutations? From there, it will be clearer (to me, at least) how you intend to "explode" your processing. Thanks!

Comment: I’d want to compare the FieldAdjStrokes from two different Names within the same Round & End_Date. But I was wondering if there’s a way to have it automatically cross-check all of them or if I’d have to go one by one